# C++ Array Processing

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

I am having trouble debugging this code so it reads two columns from the file and when the first column (Department is the same it just adds the second column to the old dept already created)This code is having trouble with looping. Any walk through, help would be much appreciated ! Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

ifstream inputFile;                   //stream object


int main()
{
inputFile.open("text.txt");

const int SIZE = 15;
int candy[SIZE];
int dept[SIZE];
int valuecounter = 0;
int Candy;
int Department;

while (inputFile >> Department >> Candy)
{
    // Exit loop if we have filled the entire array
    if (valuecounter == SIZE)
        break;

    // Update previous values
    for (int index = 0; index < valuecounter; index++)
    {
        if (dept[index] == Department)
        {
            candy[index] += Candy;
        }
    }

    // Update current values and increment counter
    dept[valuecounter] = Department;
    candy[valuecounter] = Candy;
    valuecounter++;
}

for (int i = 0; i < valuecounter ; i++)
    cout << dept[i] << "  " << candy[i] << endl;

inputFile.close();
return 0;

}
```

and the list of input being for ex:

```
910  8
450  9
750  10
150  35
750  19
150  18
910  19
390  19
520  6
110  78
300  23
110  1
110  5
120  6
150  16
300  23
110  1
110  5
120  6
150  16
```

the array should be partially filled. but it produces weird outcome! logic error?

Comment: It would be best not to use NULL at all, even for pointers, but at least don't use it for ints.  Just way too surprising.  I did a quadruple check on that code just for that.

Comment: What kind of "trouble" does it have?

Comment: looping and adding everything, once it finishes some departments that are outputted are duplicated and the second column not properly added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int main()
{

const int SIZE = 15;         
int candy[SIZE];             
int dept[SIZE];              
int valuecounter = 0;        
int Candy;                  
int Department;             

inputFile.open("text.txt");
if (!inputFile)
{
    cout << "\nError opening file" << endl
        << "Exiting\n" << endl;
    exit(1);
}
while (valuecounter < SIZE && inputFile >> Department >> Candy)
{
    //setting bool to false everytime loop starts over.
    bool found = false;

    for (int index = 0; index < valuecounter; index++)
    {
        if (dept[index] == Department)
        {
            candy[index] += Candy;
            //setting bool to true if department found
            found = true;
        }
    }
    if (!found)
    {
        dept[valuecounter] = Department;
        candy[valuecounter] = Candy;
        valuecounter++;
    }
}

inputFile.close();



if (valuecounter == 0)
{
    cout << "\n\nEMPTY FILE\nExiting.\n\n" << endl;
    exit(1);
}

here i had three different functions do different things with data


return 0;

}
```

basically what i was missing is to set bool back to false whenever while loop started over this is why data wasn't calculated properly. Anyways Thank you all for help and all the tips!

Answer (score 0):

You have initialized `valuecounter`, and all elements of array `dept`, to zero. For this reason, in every iteration of the `while` loop, condition `dept[valuecounter] == NULL` will always evaluate to `true`. This means that, in every iteration, only code in the first `if` statement will execute.

Note that this is not the only problem with this code. As user Crazy Eddie pointed out, using `NULL` as an integer is considered very bad practice.

EDIT:

Replace your while loop with the following:

```
while (inputFile >> Department >> Candy)
{
    // If this Department already exists ...
    for (int index = 0; index < valuecounter; index++)
    {
        if (dept[index] == Department)
        {
            // ... update the corresponding value in 'candy' and continue the loop
            candy[index] += Candy;
            continue;
        }
    }

    // If this Department does not exist, and if there are are more
    // available array elements, assign a new Department
    if (valuecounter < SIZE)
    {            
        dept[valuecounter] = Department;
        candy[valuecounter] = Candy;
        valuecounter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello! thank you for your help but assuming that the array is empty and it will be partially filled how do i bypass this issue?  when i check the value with the array before putting it in it. btw thank you guys for the NULL comment!

Comment: @uszy123345 I've updated my answer. Btw, note that you did not explain well in you question what you want to do. Next time you post a question, please try to be more specific. Hope the update helps.

Comment: Hello, unfortunately this does not work i uploaded the ex list that should be processed so we can have better understanding of how the output should look like. Thank you for your time! and I will keep these things  in mind next time Thank you.

Comment: @uszy123345 OK, I think I finally understand what you want:
1. The first time a new department number is read from file, a new array element is filled.
2. If there already is a department with the same number, then update the current value
of candy in corresponding array and do not fill new array element.
Please verify that this is true, and I will update my answer.

Comment: @uszy123345 I've edited my answer. Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: yes thats correct! It took me a while but i already figured it out and completed the code